# How do I obtain the GWT widget that wraps a given DOM element?

Tags: events, dom, gwt, widget

When a click event occurs, I want to determine which of my widgets was clicked. Note that, for performance reasons, I specifically don't want to add click handlers to each of my widgets.

It's easy enough to obtain the element that was clicked (it'll be the event target of the native event), but then how do I find the corresponding widget?

Comment: Do you have a demonstrable performance problem if you add click handlers to all of your widgets? Once compiled into JavaScript there will be no appreciable difference between the speed of GWT click events and "native" events.

Comment: Short answer: no. But it makes sense to me that one click handler (at a high level in the DOM tree) will be better than thousands. Isn't taking advantage of event bubbling in that way A Good Thing?

Comment: I don't see how a monolithic click handler that has to iterate through a set of possible clicked widgets is any better than utilizing the browser's event dispatch system. Don't give yourself extra work and slough off the convenience of using GWT's included support for click handlers unless you have a real, tested problem for which this would be a solution.

Comment: You know, I think you're right. I'm going to put a click handler on each widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard functionality for it, afaik. But you can do it in a similar way as is done in GWT's `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Tree` class.

Basically it work there by first collecting the chain of Elements from the Element of your root Widget to the element of the Widget that clicked (see private method `collectElementChain` in Tree class). With this chain of Elements the Widget is found by traversing from the Root widget down to the Widget clicked (see private method `findItemByChain` in the Tree class).

This works for Tree because the Widget and Element index of the children of each Widget/Element match, and because it only allows a specific widget set as TreeItem's.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can get the widget associated with the main element of a widget using either [gwtquery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/GettingStarted#Manipulating_your_widgets) or the `DOM.getEventListener(element)` method which returns the widget associated with an element.

You can check out my response in another thread for some working code: [GWT - How to retrive real clicked widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855096/gwt-how-to-retrive-real-clicked-widget/17863305#17863305)