# GWT - How to retrieve real clicked widget?

Tags: gwt, onclick, widget

I have onClick event on somePanel. And I click on it and it works. But.. How to retrieve real click target? When I click on panel which is inside od somePanel it show me that I click on somePanel..

I know we have this:

```
Element e = Element.as( event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());
```

But i returns element - I want widget..

How to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I obtain the GWT widget that wraps a given DOM element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099480/how-do-i-obtain-the-gwt-widget-that-wraps-a-given-dom-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the feature in [gwtquery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) to get the widget associated with a given element: https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/GettingStarted#Manipulating_your_widgets

```java
Widget = $(e).widget();
```

The problem is that the element clicked couldn't be the element associated with the widget but a child. In this case you could use gquery selectors to traverse the dom until you get its parent widget based on some css property.

```java
// Most gwt widgets contains a class .gwt- but this could fail
// so use a more accurate selector than the one in this example
Widget = $(e).closest("[class*='.gwt-']")
```

If you wanted to do it by yourself, taking a look to the method `getAssociatedWidget` in `GQuery` gives you the solution:

```java
  EventListener listener = DOM.getEventListener(e);
  // No listener attached to the element, so no widget exist for this element
  if (listener == null) {
    return null;
  }
  if (listener instanceof Widget) {
    // GWT uses the widget as event listener
    return (Widget) listener;
  }
```

EDITED: here you have a working example:

```java
import static com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery.*;

  // A panel with some widgets
  Panel panel = new VerticalPanel();
  final HTML widget1 = new HTML("<span>Foo</span> <span>Bar</span");
  final HTML widget2 = new HTML("<span>Foo</span> <span>Bar</span");
  final HTML widget3 = new HTML("<span>Foo</span> <span>Bar</span");
  panel.add(widget1);
  panel.add(widget2);
  panel.add(widget3);

  // we need to wrap our panel with a widget supporting click events
  FocusPanel wrapper = new FocusPanel();
  wrapper.add(panel);
  RootPanel.get().add(wrapper);

  wrapper.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
      // The element is not the HTML widget clicked but the span element
      Element e = event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().cast();

      // Using gquery to get the closest widget to the clicked element
      // We take advanrage of HTML widgets having gwt-HTML class
      Widget w = $(e).closest(".gwt-HTML").widget();

      if (w == widget1) {
        Window.alert("Clicked on widget 1");
      } else if (w == widget2) {
        Window.alert("Clicked on widget 2");
      } else if (w == widget3) {
        Window.alert("Clicked on widget 3");
      } else {
        Window.alert("Clicked on a non GWT HTML widget");
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thank's for respond :) It sounds good.. But, how to use it in onClick event? panel.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
@Override public void onClick(ClickEvent event) { 


// here I want clicked widget..

} });

Comment: Actually the only thing is to get the element in the way you say in your query, and then use gquery like I said. Edited my response with a working example

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but both answers are wrong.  If you are using a GWT EventListener and want the widget that is the source of the event, then you simply use the `event.getSource()` method of the event and cast it to the original object type.

Unless there is something that I am missing in the question here.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach, if you already know all of the widgets that you want to check against, would be to use the DOM.isOrHasChild(Element) or Element.isOrHasChild(Node).

For example:

```
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

    Element targetElem = Element.as(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());

    Widget targetWidget = null;

    if (widgetA.getElement().isOrHasChild(targetElem) {
        targetWidget = widgetA;
    }
    else if (widgetB.getElement().isOrHasChild(targetElem) {
        targetWidget = widgetA;
    }
    .....

    if (targetWidget != null) {
        // You found you widget - Yay!
    }
    else {
        // No widget found - Bummer!
    }

}
```

This approach only works if you know the widgets you are testing against up front. The benefit is that you now have an particular widget reference rather then a generic reference to 'some' widget that you might have to do additional checks against.

For example, you could have done the following if widgetA was a subclass of TextBox called MySpecialTextBox:

```
MySpecialTextBox widgetA;

if (widgetA.getElement().isOrHasChild(targetElem) {
    widgetA.someSpecialMethod();
}
```